# PHP recursively apply a function to some array members, starting at a given index and walking through the array members till a given value

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

Workin on PHP Version 5.6.33, I need to iterate through each member of a given array,  with the following restrictions:

1) Need to iterate starting from a defined index,  not from the 0 index or the first member of the array.

2) Need to iterate a given number of times,  but not through the whole array,  instead walk to array members till the given number of times is reached.

Here is an example:

```
$arr = array(0,0,0,0,0,0);
$repetitions = 10;
$startingIndex = 3;
function add($value, 1) {
   return $value + 1;
}
```

walk through each array member, starting at index 3,  10 times,  adding 1 to each array member:

```
0 => 0
1 => 0
2 => 0
3 => 0 + 1
4 => 0 + 1
5 => 0 + 1
6 => 0 + 1
```

here I have walked 4 times,  6 are left:

```
0 => 0 + 1
1 => 0 + 1
2 => 0 + 1
3 => 0 + 1 + 1
4 => 0 + 1 + 1
5 => 0 + 1 + 1
6 => 0 + 1
```

so the final result is :

```
0 => 1
1 => 1
2 => 1
3 => 2
4 => 2
5 => 2
6 => 1
```

I obviously had made my work and tried **array_map**, **array_walk**, **foreach**, **list**, **each** (deprecated), but reading PHP manual,  I encounter that those functions aim to affect "every" array member.  Instead I need to affect some array members.

Comment: split the array first

Comment: Sounds like a `for` loop with specific start and stop points. I think you may be trying to over engineer this

Comment: Can we rely on the array keys? I. e. will $arr always be the same as array_values($arr).

Comment: Your title is scary, and tells me you should probably approach this differently. I'd advise on the approach but your example is meaningless as it has no logic towards what you are doing or why. I could be wrong but on face value this smells a bit. What is the real data and reason you are approaching it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cycle through an array starting at a particular offset, you'd have a loop that resets the index:

```
function increment(& $arr, $idx, $times) {
    for ($i = 0, $p = $idx; $i < $times; ++$i) {
        $arr[$p++] += 1;

        if ($p == count($arr)) {
            $p = 0;
        }
    }
}

$arr = array(0,0,0,0,0,0);
increment($arr, 3, 10);
var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function add($array,$start,$elements,$add) {
    for($i = $start; $i < $start + $elements; $i++) {
        $array[$i] += $add;
    }

    return $array ;
}
```